# Datatable is not displaying data

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have created a datatable using data from database. you can see the code  below fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/VidyaSajeev/zq7j97c4/834/

```js
var data_table, row_num = 1,
  col_num = 11,
  row_cell = 1,
  col_cell = 0,
  iter = 0;
var cols = [];

var data = [{
  "StopName": "Udhna Darwaza",
  "1": "07:01:00",
  "2": "07:16:00",
  "3": "07:31:00",
  "4": "07:46:00",
  "5": "08:01:00",
  "6": "08:16:00",
  "7": "08:31:00",
  "8": "08:46:00",
  "9": "09:01:00",
  "10": "09:16:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Kharwar Nagar",
  "1": "07:02:00",
  "2": "07:17:00",
  "3": "07:32:00",
  "4": "07:47:00",
  "5": "08:02:00",
  "6": "08:17:00",
  "7": "08:32:00",
  "8": "08:47:00",
  "9": "09:02:00",
  "10": "09:17:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Satya Nagar",
  "1": "07:03:00",
  "2": "07:18:00",
  "3": "07:33:00",
  "4": "07:48:00",
  "5": "08:03:00",
  "6": "08:18:00",
  "7": "08:33:00",
  "8": "08:48:00",
  "9": "09:03:00",
  "10": "09:18:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Udhna Tran Rasta",
  "1": "07:04:00",
  "2": "07:19:00",
  "3": "07:34:00",
  "4": "07:49:00",
  "5": "08:04:00",
  "6": "08:19:00",
  "7": "08:34:00",
  "8": "08:49:00",
  "9": "09:04:00",
  "10": "09:19:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Udhna Bus Stand",
  "1": "07:05:00",
  "2": "07:20:00",
  "3": "07:35:00",
  "4": "07:50:00",
  "5": "08:05:00",
  "6": "08:20:00",
  "7": "08:35:00",
  "8": "08:50:00",
  "9": "09:05:00",
  "10": "09:20:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Udhna Academy",
  "1": "07:06:00",
  "2": "07:21:00",
  "3": "07:36:00",
  "4": "07:51:00",
  "5": "08:06:00",
  "6": "08:21:00",
  "7": "08:36:00",
  "8": "08:51:00",
  "9": "09:06:00",
  "10": "09:21:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Laxmi Narayan Temple",
  "1": "07:07:00",
  "2": "07:22:00",
  "3": "07:37:00",
  "4": "07:52:00",
  "5": "08:07:00",
  "6": "08:22:00",
  "7": "08:37:00",
  "8": "08:52:00",
  "9": "09:07:00",
  "10": "09:22:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Daksheswar Mahadev",
  "1": "07:08:00",
  "2": "07:23:00",
  "3": "07:38:00",
  "4": "07:53:00",
  "5": "08:08:00",
  "6": "08:23:00",
  "7": "08:38:00",
  "8": "08:53:00",
  "9": "09:08:00",
  "10": "09:23:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Pandesara G.I.D.C.",
  "1": "07:09:00",
  "2": "07:24:00",
  "3": "07:39:00",
  "4": "07:54:00",
  "5": "08:09:00",
  "6": "08:24:00",
  "7": "08:39:00",
  "8": "08:54:00",
  "9": "09:09:00",
  "10": "09:24:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Kamnath Mahadev",
  "1": "07:10:00",
  "2": "07:25:00",
  "3": "07:40:00",
  "4": "07:55:00",
  "5": "08:10:00",
  "6": "08:25:00",
  "7": "08:40:00",
  "8": "08:55:00",
  "9": "09:10:00",
  "10": "09:25:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Navin Flourine",
  "1": "07:11:00",
  "2": "07:26:00",
  "3": "07:41:00",
  "4": "07:56:00",
  "5": "08:11:00",
  "6": "08:26:00",
  "7": "08:41:00",
  "8": "08:56:00",
  "9": "09:11:00",
  "10": "09:26:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Bhestan Naher",
  "1": "07:12:00",
  "2": "07:27:00",
  "3": "07:42:00",
  "4": "07:57:00",
  "5": "08:12:00",
  "6": "08:27:00",
  "7": "08:42:00",
  "8": "08:57:00",
  "9": "09:12:00",
  "10": "09:27:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Bhagwati Industrial Estate",
  "1": "07:13:00",
  "2": "07:28:00",
  "3": "07:43:00",
  "4": "07:58:00",
  "5": "08:13:00",
  "6": "08:28:00",
  "7": "08:43:00",
  "8": "08:58:00",
  "9": "09:13:00",
  "10": "09:28:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Unn Naka",
  "1": "07:14:00",
  "2": "07:29:00",
  "3": "07:44:00",
  "4": "07:59:00",
  "5": "08:14:00",
  "6": "08:29:00",
  "7": "08:44:00",
  "8": "08:59:00",
  "9": "09:14:00",
  "10": "09:29:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Unn Industrial Estate",
  "1": "07:15:00",
  "2": "07:30:00",
  "3": "07:45:00",
  "4": "08:00:00",
  "5": "08:15:00",
  "6": "08:30:00",
  "7": "08:45:00",
  "8": "09:00:00",
  "9": "09:15:00",
  "10": "09:30:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Unn Char Rasta",
  "1": "07:16:00",
  "2": "07:31:00",
  "3": "07:46:00",
  "4": "08:01:00",
  "5": "08:16:00",
  "6": "08:31:00",
  "7": "08:46:00",
  "8": "09:01:00",
  "9": "09:16:00",
  "10": "09:31:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Green Park",
  "1": "07:17:00",
  "2": "07:32:00",
  "3": "07:47:00",
  "4": "08:02:00",
  "5": "08:17:00",
  "6": "08:32:00",
  "7": "08:47:00",
  "8": "09:02:00",
  "9": "09:17:00",
  "10": "09:32:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Sachin G.I.D.C.",
  "1": "07:18:00",
  "2": "07:33:00",
  "3": "07:48:00",
  "4": "08:03:00",
  "5": "08:18:00",
  "6": "08:33:00",
  "7": "08:48:00",
  "8": "09:03:00",
  "9": "09:18:00",
  "10": "09:33:00"
}, {
  "StopName": "Sachin GIDC Naka",
  "1": "07:30:00",
  "2": "07:45:00",
  "3": "08:00:00",
  "4": "08:15:00",
  "5": "08:30:00",
  "6": "08:45:00",
  "7": "09:00:00",
  "8": "09:15:00",
  "9": "09:30:00",
  "10": "09:45:00"
}];

//Get stored data from HTML table element
var results = [];

function initDT() {
  debugger;
  //Construct the measurement table
  data_table = $('#example').dataTable({
    "bJQueryUI": true,
    "bDeferRender": true,
    "bInfo": false,
    "bSort": false,
    "bDestroy": true,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bPagination": false,
    "aaData": results,
    "aoColumns": cols,
  });
  attachTableClickEventHandlers();
}

function fnCreatedRow(nRow, aData, iDataIndex) {
  var sURL = aData[6];
  var t = "<img src='" + sURL + "' width='90' height='126'>";
  $(nRow).attr('tooltip-title', t);
}

function fnDrawCallback(settings) {
  $(".tooltip-card-name").each(function(i, td) {
    var title = $(td).parent().attr('tooltip-title');
    $(td).tooltip({
      "delay": 0,
      "track": true,
      "fade": 250,
      content: title
    })
  });
}

function GetSchedules() {
  cols = [];
  var returnedData = data;
  if (returnedData.length > 0) {
    var obj = returnedData[0];
    for (var key in obj) {
      var attrName = key;
      var attrValue = obj[key];
      var column = {
        "mData": key,
        "mDataProp": key,
        "sTitle": key,
        "sType": "string",
        "fnCreatedCell": function(nTd, sData, oData, iRow, iCol) {
          if (iCol == 0) {
            nTd.title = $(nTd).text();
            if ($(nTd).text().length > 3) {
              $(nTd).text($(nTd).text().substring(0, 3).concat("..."));
            }
          }
        }
      };
      cols.push(column);
    }
  }
  debugger;
  results = returnedData;
  //$('#example').dataTable().fnClearTable();
  initDT();
  addDBClikHandler();
}

function attachTableClickEventHandlers() {
  //row/column indexing is zero based
  $("#example thead tr th").click(function() {    
    col_num = parseInt($(this).index());
    console.log("column_num =" + col_num);  
  });
  $("#example tbody tr td").click(function() {    
    col_cell = parseInt($(this).index());
    row_cell = parseInt($(this).parent().index());   
    console.log("Row_num =" + row_cell + "  ,  column_num =" + col_cell);
  });
};


$("#btnAddRow").click(function() {
  //adding/removing row from datatable datasource
  //create test new record
  var aoCols = data_table.fnSettings().aoColumns;
  var newRow = new Object();
  for (var iRec = 0; iRec < aoCols.length; iRec++) {

    if (aoCols[iRec]._sManualType === "date") {
      newRow[aoCols[iRec].mDataProp] = "2011/03/25";
    } else if (aoCols[iRec]._sManualType === "numeric") {
      newRow[aoCols[iRec].mDataProp] = 10;
    } else if (aoCols[iRec]._sManualType === "string") {
      newRow[aoCols[iRec].mDataProp] = 'testStr';
    }
  }
  results.splice(row_cell + 1, 0, newRow);
  data_table.fnDestroy();
  initDT();
  addDBClikHandler();
});

$('#btnAddCol').click(function() {

  //new column information
  //row's new field(for new column)
  //cols must be updated
  cols.splice(col_num + 1, 0, {
    "mDataProp": "newField" + iter,
    sTitle: "Col-" + iter,
    sType: "string"
  });
  //update the result, actual data to be displayed
  for (var iRes = 0; iRes < results.length; iRes++) {
    results[iRes]["newField" + iter] = "data-" + iter;
  }
  //destroy the table
  data_table.fnDestroy();
  $("#example thead tr th").eq(col_num).after('<th>Col-' + iter + '</th>');
  //init again
  initDT();
  iter++;
  addDBClikHandler();
});

function restoreRow(oTable, nRow) {
  var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
  var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);

  for (var i = 0, iLen = jqTds.length; i < iLen; i++) {
    oTable.fnUpdate(aData[i], nRow, i, false);
  }
};

function editRow(oTable, nRow) {
  var aData = oTable.fnGetData(nRow);
  var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
  jqTds[col_cell].innerHTML = '<input type="text" id ="typ" value="' + aData[cols[col_cell].mData] + '"/>';
  $("#typ").autocomplete({
    source: type1
  });
};

function saveRow(oTable, nRow) {
  var jqInputs = $('input', nRow);
  oTable.fnUpdate(jqInputs[0].value, row_cell, col_cell, false);
};

jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
  "date-uk-pre": function(a) {
    var ukDatea = a.split('/');
    return (ukDatea[2] + ukDatea[1] + ukDatea[0]) * 1
  },

  "date-uk-asc": function(a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? -1 : ((a > b) ? 1 : 0));
  },

  "date-uk-desc": function(a, b) {
    return ((a < b) ? 1 : ((a > b) ? -1 : 0));
  }
});

/* Get the rows which are currently selected */
function fnGetSelected(oTableLocal) {
  var aReturn = new Array();
  var aTrs = oTableLocal.fnGetNodes();

  for (var i = 0; i < aTrs.length; i++) {
    if ($(aTrs[i]).hasClass('row_selected')) {
      aReturn.push(aTrs[i]);
    }
  }
  return aReturn;
};

function addDBClikHandler() {
  $('#example tbody tr').on('dblclick', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var nRow = $(this)[0];

    var jqTds = $('>td', nRow);
    if ($.trim(jqTds[0].innerHTML.substr(0, 6)) != '<input') {
      if (nEditing !== null && nEditing != nRow) {
        /* Currently editing - but not this row - restore the old before continuing to edit mode */
        restoreRow(oTable, nEditing);
        nEditing = nRow;
        editRow(oTable, nRow);

      } else {
        /* No edit in progress - let's start one */
        nEditing = nRow;
        editRow(oTable, nRow);

      }

    }


  });

  $('#example tbody tr').keydown(function(event) {

    if (event.keyCode == 13) {
      event.preventDefault();

      if (nEditing == null)
        alert("Select Row");
      else
        saveRow(oTable, nEditing);
      nEditing = null;
    }
    /* Editing this row and want to save it */

  });


};

var nEditing = null;

var oTable = null;

$(document).ready(function() {
  GetSchedules();
  initDT();
  oTable = data_table;
  addDBClikHandler();
});
```

```html
Select any col/row to add col/row after/below it
<br/>
<button type="button" id="btnAddRow">Add new row</button>
<button type="button" id="btnAddCol">Add new column</button>
<br>
<table class="dataTable" id="example">
</table>
```

Actually here the table heading is trip no and virtual vehicle id.if there is no virtual vehicleId table is showing only heading.Please check below jsfiddle for the same
http://jsfiddle.net/VidyaSajeev/zq7j97c4/866/

here the change i made is in first link i have given data as 
 **"1": "07:01:00",
  "2": "07:16:00",**
and in second sample the data is 
**"1(2)": "07:01:00",
  "1()": "07:16:00",**
Please let me know if anybody know the reason for this issue

Comment: `<br>` does not need or use a closing slash.

Comment: Start by referring to some CDN-files that actually exists :) Neither the dataTable nor the jeditable reference is valid URI's.

Comment: please check jsfiddle.. its working fine

Comment: instead of "1(2)": "07:01:00", "1()": "07:16:00", if i give a blank space between the brackets like given below is also  working fine.
"1(2)": "07:01:00", "1( )": "07:16:00",